# How to effectively clip the amount of entries in a dictionary?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary

I had a `List<myClass> myList` for storing a list of items.

When I had to clip this (discard any amount of items above some threshold) I used:

```
 myList.RemoveRange(threshold, myList.Count - threshold);
```

where threshold is the max amount of things the list can contain

Now I've upgraded the datatype to a `Dictionary<key, myClass> myDictionary`

How can I basically do the same: Discard all entries above some threshold. (It doesn't matter which ones are discarded)

I guess I could foreach through the keys collection and manually delete all keys/value pairs. But I was hoping there was a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code will trim a `Dictionary` named `dict` to the maximum size specified by `maxSize`.

```
foreach (var obj in dict.Keys.Skip(maxSize).ToList()) dict.Remove(obj);
```

Comment: +1 Elegant solution! You could pack this into a extension method like: `public static void Trim<TKey, TValue>(this IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dict, int max) { foreach (TKey key in dict.Keys.Skip(max).ToList()) dict.Remove(key); }`